# Index in Oracle for JOIN does not seem to improve performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, join, indexing

I am trying to improve a query performance using index:

```
SELECT E.CLIENT, E.TITLE                     
FROM (SELECT  D.CLIENT, D.TITLE, COUNT('X') TEMPORADAS
      FROM  (SELECT A.CLIENT, A.TITLE
                FROM (SELECT CLIENT,TITLE,SEASON, COUNT('X') N_EPISODIOS
                       FROM LIC_SERIES GROUP BY CLIENT,TITLE,SEASON) A
                JOIN SEASONS B ON (A.TITLE=B.TITLE AND A.SEASON=B.SEASON AND A.N_EPISODIOS=B.EPISODES)) D
      GROUP BY D.CLIENT, D.TITLE) E
JOIN SERIES F ON (E.TITLE=F.TITLE AND E.TEMPORADAS=F.TOTAL_SEASONS)
```

The main idea was to create two index, with the values that are in the ON clause from the inner query (the deepest JOIN):

```
DROP INDEX INDEX_TAPS_MOVIES;
DROP INDEX INDEX_CASTS;

CREATE INDEX INDEX_TAPS_MOVIES
ON TAPS_MOVIES(TITLE);


CREATE INDEX INDEX_CONTRACTS
ON CASTS(TITLE);
```

But after analyse the result, there is not any improvement in the load time... I have trying to force using Hints but I get even worst performance. What could be the key to use Index in these type of queries?
Should be a better way to optimize it rather than index?

Kindest Regards

Comment: Did you look at your explain plan?

Comment: Look into [rollups and cubes](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets) instead of nesting subqueries.

Comment: @dmfay a rollup wouldn't increase the number of rows fetched?

Comment: @OldProgrammer yes, I look at my explain plan, an it looks like its using the index, but not better performance at all

Answer (score 0):

Oracle optimizer do not always use indexs. it checks diffrent  execution plans and choose the best one.sometimes not using the index return better performance.
to improve performance you can parrallel your table(see the parallelizem in oracle).
for make a table to execute parrallel  use following code :
    ALTER TABLES YourTableName  PARALLEL 4;

or you can use hint as follow :
    /*+ PARALLEL(4) */
be carfull about parallelizem's degree.

Comment: Thanks! it looks like it improve a little the performance, but maybe a 2-5%. But this only improve the select, and the bottleneck is in the JOIN, not other way to improve that?

Comment: make parallel all tables which attend in join.

Comment: but int this case will be something like: SELECT `/*+ parallel(A) parallel(B)*/ A.CLIENT, A.TITLE` ?

Comment: try this :
    ALTER TABLES LIC_SERIES  PARALLEL 4;
    ALTER TABLES SEASONS  PARALLEL 4;
    ALTER TABLES SERIES   PARALLEL 4;